# Prove, by contradiction, that if a and b are nonzero real numbers, and $a<\frac{1}{a}<b<\frac{1}{b}$ then $a<−1$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

**Prove, by contradiction, that if a and b are nonzero real numbers, and $a<1/a<b<1/b$ then $a<−1$.**

I understand that the first step is to assume that $a<1/a<b<1/b$ is true. Therefore, the hypotheses makes up:

$a ≠ 0$

$b ≠ 0$

$a<1/a<b<1/b$ is true

From here, to prove by contradiction, we find the negated version of $ a < -1$ which is $ a => -1 $.

Now we must find a contradiction within these statements, but I am struggling to pinpoint that contradiction.

FYI Answer:
I have accepted the completed answer for those who are looking for a quick answer but do check the other one for in-depth
analysis as well.

Comment: Deal with the two cases $a<0$ and $a>0$ separately.

Comment: Trick is.  If $c$ is positive $c < \frac 1c \iff c < 1 \iff 1 < \frac 1c \iff c < 1 < \frac 1c$.  So if $a,b$ are both positive $a < \frac 1a < b < \frac 1b \implies a < 1 < \frac 1a < b < 1< \frac 1b$ is a contradiction.  So $a$ is not positive.  You'll get a different contradiction (one that doesn't involve $b$) if you assume $-1 \le a < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose $-1\le a$, i.e $a\in [-1,\infty)$.

Note that $a$ cannot be larger than $1$ or be in $(-1,0)$, otherwise, $\frac{1}{a}<a$. And $a$ cannot be $-1$ or $1$. otherwise, $\frac{1}{a}=a$. Therefore, $a\in(0,1)$ and $1<\frac{1}{a}$

But, there is $b$ such that $1<\frac{1}{a}<b$, thereofre, $\frac{1}{b}<1<b$, which contradicts to the assumption that $b<\frac{1}{b}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This defo helped to finish the question and my understanding. How do you come around to developing this quick level of understanding and do you have a source of further proof questions. I am working through the "How to Prove it? by Vellenman but need further practice...

Comment: @BlueSky if you want to know more of this kind of questions, you can read some introductory book to real analysis, e.g Introduction to real analysis by Bartle.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to note that $1$ is always between $|c|$ and $\frac 1{|c|}$ and So if $c \ne \pm 1$ then either you have have $0 < c < 1 < \frac 1c$ or $0< \frac 1c < \pm < c$ or $c < -1 < \frac 1c < 0$ or $\frac 1c < -1 < c < 0$.

So if $a < \frac 1a < b < \frac 1b$ then $a < \pm 1 < \frac 1a < b < \pm 1 < \frac 1b$.

Now there are only two possible $\pm 1$, $-1, 1$ and $-1< 1$ so si you have $\pm 1 < \pm 1$ the only true statement that makes sense is $-1 < 1$ so $a < -1 < \frac 1a < b < 1 < \frac 1b$.

and ... okay that was a *direct* proof and you were asked for a proof by contradiction:

......

Note that If $a < 0$ then $a < \frac 1a \implies a^2 > 1$ and $|a| >1$ so if $a<0$ then $a<-1$.

As we are assuming *both* $a \ge -1$ and $a < \frac 1a$ so that means $a \ge 0$ and as $a\ne 0$ we have $a > 0$.  So $a< \frac 1a \implies a^2 < 1$ and $|a| < 1$ so $0 < a < 1$.  Which means $\frac 1a > 1$

So we have $0 < a < 1 < \frac 1a$.

Can you finish?

If we assume $0 < a < 1 < \frac 1a < b < \frac 1b$ then $b > 1>0$ and .....

Comment: Yes, I managed to finish it. I appreciate the help and I think I am slowly getting to grips with Proofs. Do you have any sources of further questions for proofs? I am working through the "How to Prove it? by Vellenman and need further questions. FYI: selected other answer but credited you in amended question!